# How to configure nginx when using Helm to install?

Tags: .net, nginx, asp.net-core, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

According to this article one need to set some nginx properties when running a .NET Core 2.x application using https and Azure AD Authentication behind Nginx in a Kubernetes cluster:

[.Net Core behind NGINX returns 502 Bad Gateway after authentication by IdentityServer4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964429/net-core-behind-nginx-returns-502-bad-gateway-after-authentication-by-identitys)

The answer outlines how to do this for a regular Nginx installation, but I would like to do this when installing Nginx in a Kubernetes cluster using Helm.

These are the Nginx properties one need to set:

```
nginx.conf:
    http{
    ...
    proxy_buffer_size   128k;
    proxy_buffers   4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    ...
    }


default.conf:
location /{
    ...
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ...
}
```

The command I use to install Nginx in the Kubernetes cluster is:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --namespace kube-system
```

How does one set the above properties when installing Nginx using Helm in a Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to customize nginx configuration using ConfigMap.
[This is an example](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/customization/custom-configuration)
after adding the ConfigMap if nginx doesn't get updated, update your nginx chart using Helm:
`helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART]`
`heml upgrade my-release stable/nginx-ingress`
if you don't know the [RELEASE] use following command:
`helm list`

Comment: I'm trying to test changing the config values using the ConfigMap, but have not managed to get rid of the 502 Bad Gateway yet. I have created a documentation of steps I used at the bottom of this article: https://github.com/olavt/AzureKubernetes Can you see any obvious mistakes?

Comment: My problem may be related to having to also override fastcgi_buffers and fastcgi_buffer_size. How to I customize these in the Helm install?

Answer (score 1):

Fully agree with @Mozafar Gholami, you can change parameters using ConfigMap while deploying nginx or update your  current configuration.
To update parameters before installation suggest you next:

1.fetch chart to your local machine and unzip it:

```
helm fetch stable/nginx-ingress

tar -xzf nginx-ingress-1.1.4.tgz
```

2. edit controller.config section in the values.yml

example for you:

```
controller:
  name: controller
  image:
    repository: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller
    tag: "0.21.0"
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    # www-data -> uid 33
    runAsUser: 33

  config:
    proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
    proxy-buffers: "4 256k"
```

3.check what will be added to new configmap

```
helm   template . | less
```

4. install chart

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress --namespace kube-system ./nginx-ingress
```

Please keep in mind that:

1. Instead of ConfigMaps you can change parameters with Annotations.
2. Unfortunately NOT ALL parameters can be changed in nginx-ingress by above approach.
3. For more information reading the [nginx-ingress customization](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/configmap-and-annotations.md#Summary-of-ConfigMap-and-Annotations) page where you can find all values you are able to change. For example in your case I wasnt able to update `proxy_busy_buffers_size` and `large_client_header_buffers` parameters.

Hope this help you.

Comment: An update to this. The values needed to be changed to enter to ConfigMap are now in `controller.config.entries`. Show latest values with: `helm show values nginx-stable/nginx-ingress` and look for the format on the version you are running.

I had tons of issues with this since all references online said `controller.config`

Answer (score 1):

I found that the simplest solution is to use annotations on the Nginx ingress like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
...
```

Comment: How do I apply these settings??? What commands to I need to run?

Comment: These are not commands to run, but lines of code you insert into the Nginx ingress manifest files (yaml) for Kubernetes.